# Remove languages other than English in R

Tags: r, text-mining, data-cleaning, corpus

am performing some text mining on a large data set containing youtube comments (over 25000 comments). Unfortunately, there are a lot of comments in non-English languages, like Spanish, German or Chinese.

I managed to remove Chinese language by kicking out characters other than a-z and numbers 0-9. Here is the code:

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(function(s){
gsub(pattern = '[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+',
   x = s,
   replacement = " ",
   ignore.case = TRUE,
   perl = TRUE)})
```

However, this does not remove German or Spanish words. Do you know how to remove or detect other languages than English for text mining?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: this is too broad/looking for a tool. there is no hard-and-fast way to accomplish this due to substantial overlap among these languages. the right approach depends on what you hope to accomplish with the "cleaned" data

Comment: To specify a little bit more I thought it would be useful to include a Spanish and German dictionary as stop words and then apply the removeStopwords command...do you think this could be possible?

Comment: @Lucinho91 alternatively, you could inner join an English dictionary and only keep comments that match at least two or three English words. Anti-joining a foreign dictionary would remove comments like `Not gonna lie, amigos, I get serious schadenfreude every time I watch this video.`

Comment: the removestopwords approach is fraught because of the inverse of Andrew's admonition -- `tengo que decir 'i am the greatest' muchos vezes`

Comment: In MichaelChirico's situation I'd think you'd correctly want to remove the sentence despite the English quotation?

Comment: @AndrewBrēza thank you very much for your answer! I just started coding for my master's thesis and I am very new to all this. Could you tell me how such an inner join would look like? My code looks like this so far:
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(comments_final$textOriginal))
corpus
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[^[:space:]]*", "", x)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeURL))
removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]*", "", x) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeNumPunct))

Comment: myStopwords <- c(setdiff(stopwords('english'), c("r", "big")),
             "use", "see", "used", "via", "amp")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, myStopwords)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(function(s){
gsub(pattern = '[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+',
   x = s,
   replacement = " ",
   ignore.case = TRUE,
   perl = TRUE)}))

Comment: @CalumYou exactly, I would like to remove all non english words from my corpus or from my data frame